# Autogenerate WXI file in WiX Build process

Tags: msbuild, wix, visual-studio-2019

I have a batch file that creates a WXI file that is included in the final build process of a MSI.

If I use the "Pre-build Event" in the project setting of VS-2019 this command is always executed even if there is no need to compile the WiX project.

I tried to add

```
  <Target Name="UpdateVersionNumber" Inputs="$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\Bin\Infile.dll" Outputs="$(ProjectDir)output.wxi">
    <Exec Command="&quot;%COMSPEC%&quot; /c UpdateVersion.bat &quot;$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\Bin\Infile.dll&quot; &quot;$(ProjectDir)$output.wxi&quot;" />
  </Target>
```

The batch file creates the output.wxi file depending on the DLL. The output.wxi is also part of the project.

But it is never executed. If I add `BeforeTargets="Compile"` it is again always executed.

I only want this batch file executed if any build is required.

In C# projects the "Pre-Build Events" are only executed when there is need for a build an any file is out of date. This isn't the case for WiX projects in VS-2019.

How to achieve that this batch file is only executed when the `Infile.dll` is newer than the `output.wxi`

Edit: The `infile.dll` is not created by this build process. The build process for the `infile.dll` is completely a separate project.

Comment: Actually, I think you have a problem with the logic of the issue.You should note that wix project does not have incremental build features. So it will always execute build process. Besides, I wonder how  `Infile.dll`  is created. If it is built every time executing the build process, it is also newer to output.wxi in the first place, so the target is always executed

Comment: Only up to date for `Infile.dll`, will break that target and will not execute it.

Comment: Infile.dll ist not part of this project. Is is consumed from another project and the setup should take the version number from this DLL. This is the idea.

Comment: No never. It is old (2 months)
In facht this block has no effect. It is never executed,

Answer (score 0):

**First**, I think that there is some problems with your `Infile.dll` and your needs about this issue.

> How to achieve that this batch file is only executed when the
> Infile.dll is newer than the output.wxi

To answer this question, actually, what you did(use input and output) meets this.

If the files from the **inputs** node are newer than the files from **outputs** node, the target will be executed. See [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-build-incrementally?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN#specifying-inputs-and-outputs).

**So in your side**, the `Infile.dll` is always built rather than up to date, and it is always newer than `output.wxi` which depends on it. And the batch file will generate the `output.wxi` based on `Infile.dll`. All of these cause that behavior and the target will always be executed.

`BeforeTargets="Compile"` just specify this target into the build process.

[image]

> In C# projects the "Pre-Build Events" are only executed when there is
> need for a build an any file is out of date. This isn't the case for
> WiX projects in VS-2019.

There won't be any problems with this method on the surface. The real problem is that why the `Infile.dll` is always newer than `output.wxi`.

```
<Target Name="UpdateVersionNumber" Inputs="$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\Bin\Infile.dll" Outputs="$(ProjectDir)output.wxi" BeforeTargets="Compile">
    <Exec Command="&quot;%COMSPEC%&quot; /c UpdateVersion.bat &quot;$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\Bin\Infile.dll&quot; &quot;$(ProjectDir)$output.wxi&quot;" />
  </Target>
```

==============================

**First**, if the `Infile.dll` is one of the output file of the wix project, then it can be explained clearly. Since wix project does not have incremental build feature and always

**The execute order**

**UpdateVersionNumber(compare `Infile.dll` and `output.wxi` )**--->**Compare**-->**Build**(generate the new output file `Infile.dll`)

For the first build time, the target will be executed and then generated the `output.wxi` file based on `Infile.dll` as expected. Then it executes the build process, it will update
`Infile.dll`.

However when you execute it second time, the `Infile.dll` is newer than `output.wxi`. And the target will always be executed and stuck in a loop.

In this situation, you have nothing to do.

=============================

If `Infile.dll` is an content from somewhere else, you should check why the `Infile.dll` is always new(perhaps the wix project has a dependency relationship with the other project) rather than **up-to-date**.Or it could be always be updated by something else.

If `Infile.dll` is the output file from another type of the project, you can enter that project to check its detailed output build output log to find where the issue is.

**In addition**, you should check the other project very carefully and pay attention to your requirements.

Comment: Sorry. I disagree. infile.dll is not part of the WiX build procress. It is a file that is created by a separate build process. 
The idea is, that I want to use the same version in the WiX Setup that was used from the DLL.